# How to get past Visual Studio "Setup Error" for Unity development?

Tags: unity, visual-studio

When I launch Visual Studio from Unity on my laptop, I get the following error:

[image: Screenshot of error dialog]

> **Setup Error**
>
> The setup for this installation of Visual Studio is not complete. Please run the Visual Studio Installer again to correct the issue.

As instructed, I've tried reinstalling Visual Studio multiple times, or using the "repair" option, but nothing has resolved the error.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What actually worked was something along those lines:

1. Completely uninstall visual studio.
2. Download and install "CCleaner".
3. Use CCleaner to clean your registry.
4. Reboot your PC. (This seems really important.)
5. Download and install Visual Studio Community 2019.
6. During installation, make sure you select the game development tool package (but uncheck the unity editor installation if you already have unity installed).
7. Let the download and install finish completely without any interruptions.

(Thanks to [Alex Myers](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/120475/alex-myers) for their comment.)

---

If VS setup fails, these are alternatives:

- Visual Studio Code is also at least semi-officially supported with plug ins and ability to launch from the Unity editor.
- C# source files are just text files so you can use any text editor you wish to edit them. It won't be as nice an experience though.
- Jetbrains Rider is an alternative.
- MonoDevelop, it has less features but also lower requirements.

(Thanks to comments from [Colin Young](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/109691/colin-young) and [trollingchar](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/123089/trollingchar).)

Answer (score 0):

In "preferences", go to editor and you can choose which visual studio you are using, that's how I fixed it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).